# Unable to access Data Transfer object in WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have created a web application in .Net which will be used to consume multiple wcf service. The end points will be specified at runtime using below code:

```
ServiceWCFTest3.Service1Client client1 = new Service1Client();
            client1.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:55473/Service1.svc");
```

Also please refer below one of the web methods exposed by the service:

```
EmployeeDetails empDtl= new EmployeeDetails("John");
ResultObject result = channel.ADMSAccess_Entry("Test",empDtl );
```

These classes are marked as DataContract in the specific wcf service.

Now, when the application is executed to access multiple wcf services by changing end point at runtime, it points to correct service and correct web methods. But the value of object EmployeeDetails and ResultObject is passed and received as null. I need to use these class objects to communicate. Can anybody please suggest how can I pass the values using these objects?

Comment: Please show code how you pass these values and how you receive these in web service.

Comment: Please refer the second code snippet I have mentioned. I called the web methods this way only.

Comment: Check if the Properties and class is marked with DataMember and DataContract attribute.

Comment: Yes it is done properly. In fact this is working if I add the service reference at design time but it doesn't work when the reference end point is set at runtime.

Comment: Do all services use same contract classes? You mentioned that when adding as a service reference everything works, which makes me think that you have two different contract classes (different assemblies/namespaces) that are named similar.